# Cant access nginx server through public ip

Tags: linux, asp.net-core, nginx, vps

im learning deploy my net core app to linux vps, after install nginx and start, i cant access server through ip. Port 80 already opened. Everything seems right but nginx default page doesnt show.
**Check Port:**
[image]

**Nginx Status:**
[image]

**nginx.conf**
[image]

**site-enabled/default**
[image]

Comment: Can you show you config file ?
Port 80 already opened means that there is a procecess that use it, let it be another nginx instance or another webserver

Comment: i update pic of nginx.conf above. thanks a lot @Gianluca

Comment: Cannot see `location` property in the configuration, you might need it to serve default page

Comment: i updated default config pic in site-enabled. I do not change config, when the first time i install nginx, everything works perfectly. but then i uninstall and reinstall again i cant access default page by ip anymore @Alexander

Comment: I have the same problem with you. How did you solve this issues?
The different config is that I put my file to site-enabled/example.com.conf

Comment: try to reboot your vps. I rebooted and it work. I don't know why =))